# Using git to maintain a website

Tags: git, web

Up until today I was using git in the following manner:

- a master repo /path/www on my webserver as the document root
- a clone on my PC

I normally made large changes on the PC and pushed to the server. After doing this, I had to "git reset HEAD" and "git checkout ."  on the server.  Sometimes I would make a small change on the server and pull this back to the PC.  This all worked fine until today when, on pushing, git complained

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
etc.
```

Why, after 6-12 months working fine, should this fail now?

After finding http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto thanks to a StackOverflow question, I copied /path/www to /path/www.git and made this a 'bare' repo. The document root remains at /path/www.  I added a .git/hooks/post-receive script containing "GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/www checkout -f".

After modifying the config on the PC to point to the www.git repo, I can now push as before and the changes get uploaded and updated in the document root.  I have a few questions about this:

- the howto implies that the working tree has no .git metadata.  Is this really so? I tried removing its .git directory but "git status" no longer worked.  Setting GIT_DIR to /path/www.git did not help as git said the repo (the bare one at /path/www.git) was not in fact a repo.
- If I update index.html and add somefile.html on the PC and push these changes, these files are updated/added-to in the server's doc root.  But if I use "git status" in the doc root, it tells me that index.html has been changed and somefile.html is an untracked file. I naively expected that the "checkout -f" would have updated the working tree to exactly what I pushed from the PC.  Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the howto implies that the working tree has no .git metadata. Is this
>   really so?

Yes. You have a bare repo setup and to actually get your files for your website, you "temporarily" assign a working directory to the bare repo and check it out to the website path that you want. That is what `GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/www checkout -f` does. The `.git` that was present would have been an artifact of your previous setup before you moved to the bare repo.

> But if I use "git status" in the doc root, it tells me that
>   index.html has been changed and somefile.html is an untracked file.

Again, this seem like the effect of the presence of the `.git` from your previous setup. Delete the `/var/www/.git`

> I naively expected that the "checkout -f" would have updated the
>   working tree to exactly what I pushed from the PC.

Your expectation is right and this how it is supposed to work. Remove the `.git` as mentioned above.

To actually do a git status, go to `/var/www.git` and do `GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www git status`

PS: Why are you doing so many changes and git status on your server? Limit yourself to your PC.

Comment: Thanks, all is clear now.  Sometimes a quick vi edit on the server is quicker than emacs on the PC followed by push, reset HEAD, checkout etc - especially when correcting something that I want gone fast.  Hence my changes at the server end.  Maybe I'll refrain from that now :-)